# Remove an entry from "settings" file

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008

My application uses a settings file `settings.txt` to save the currently set values of the `controls` placed on a `form`. Each time the application starts this settings file is referred to load the settings into the application window.

I use a function named `void SaveSetting(string SettingName)` with some `switch-cases` to save the settings. Is it possible to develop a similar function named `void RemoveSetting(string SettingName)` which will remove the specified setting from `settings.txt` file altogether???

Here I don't want to remove the `get` and `set` values from `settings.cs` file but I need to delete the entry from `settings.txt` file without corrupting the file.

Also I don't want to set the value `null` or `zero` to that particular control ('cause its causing an error at run-time).

**Is it possible to remove an entry entirely from the settings file???**

Language: C#
Platform: Windows
IDE: Visual Studio 2008
.NET framework: 3.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the settings file is small, you could simply completely overwrite it each time you want to save any change (adding/removing/changing an entry). Then you don't have to worry about breaking the format.

Alternately, if you want to only append to the end of the settings file, you could define a new type of entry that removes an old entry.

Comment: Yup, the settings file is not too big and I can consider overwriting the file. Thanks for the suggestion.